# Подключение диска к Kali Linux WSL

Tags: windows, kali-linux, wsl, wsl2

Хочу подключить диск к WSL Windows, но говорит, что диск занят:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> GET-CimInstance -query "SELECT * from Win32_DiskDrive"

DeviceID           Caption             Partitions Size          Model
--------           -------             ---------- ----          -----
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 ST1000DM010-2EP102  1          1000202273280 ST1000DM010-2EP102
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 INTEL SSDSCKKW256G8 2          256052966400  INTEL SSDSCKKW256G8


PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
Диск занят или заблокирован другим процессом.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007006c
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x80070020
```

Не знаю, как завершить процессы (на диске D) без вреда для приложений. Или хотя бы узнать, какие процессы на диске D.